# Delay inside for loop

Tags: java, android

Hi  I want to implement such behaviour:
Every one second I want to get a String from List and print it.
(actually I want my view to: setVisibility(View.Visible), but it's the same thing.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    for (String str : layoutsList) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("LevelOneFragment", "tick" + str);
                i++;
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

But this solution don't work.
How should I correctly do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are setting a delay for all work on the Handler at 1000ms.  That means that each item of work will occur essentially at the same time, since the loop executes quickly.

Instead, why don't you try scheduling each item of work at an increasing delay, such as (i+1)*1000?

```
for (int i = 0; i < layoutsList.size(); i++) {
    final String str = layoutsList.get(i);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("LevelOneFragment", "tick" + str);
        }
    }, (i+1)*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to block the UI thread? :-(

```
for (String str : layoutsList) {
   Log.d("LevelOneFragment", "tick" + str);
   i++;
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: UI blocking is actually a bad thing! Can you make the same, but without UI blocking? I've edited my answer.